# usage of busy in these sentences

Tags: word-usage

hie, I want to know which of these sentences are correct or are better to be used.

He got busied cooking his dinner.

He busied himself cooking his dinner.

He busied himself with cooking his dinner.

He busied cooking his dinner.

thank you

Comment: _Busy_ as a verb requires a reflexive object, with an optional complement clause. So if _He_ is the subject of the verb _busy_, _himself_ must be the direct object, followed optionally by a clause like _cooking dinner_. To _busy oneself_ means the same thing as _get busy_, but it requires the reflexive pronoun.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote

> *Busy* as a verb requires a reflexive object, with an optional complement clause. So if *He* is the subject of the verb *busy*, *himself* must be the direct object, followed optionally by a clause like *cooking dinner*. To *busy oneself* means the same thing as *get busy*, but it requires the reflexive pronoun.